# Change HTML as an INT onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I call a JavaScript function when an image is clicked, I want to be able to get a value which is on the screen already and add or subtract to it. This is the function I have tried:

```
function addValue(){
    var value = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
    parseInt(value, 10);
    var totalValue = value+10;    
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = totalValue;
    }
```

This is a basic test, I am trying to make the value add 10 each time. EG: 0 ->10 ->20...
but this just outputs another 10 string on click, EG: 0 -> 010 -> 01010....

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseInt` function *returns* a `Number`, it doesn't change your existing `value` variable.

Try this instead:

```
value = parseInt(value, 10);
```

Or better yet:

```
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").innerHTML, 10);
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

```
function addValue(){
   var value = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
   value=parseInt(value, 10);
   var totalValue = value+10;    
   document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = totalValue;
}
```